# Enable basic security with error could not resolve type id 'basic' into a subtype

Tags: java, security, druid

**Affected Version**

- durid version: apache-druid-0.16.0-incubating
- jdk version :jdk1.8.0_172-cloudera

**Description**

I want to enable my single-server "basic security" via guide https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/druid-basic-security.html
But I got error when I run start-micro-quickstart.

logs show:
Could not resolve type id 'basic' into a subtype of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.server.security.Authorizer]: known type ids = [Authorizer, allowAll]
at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]

[The more detail to see github issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-druid/issues/8831)

*My common.runtime.properties is as follows:*

```
# Basic Security

druid.auth.authenticatorChain=["MyBasicAuthenticator"]
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.type=basic
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.initialAdminPassword=password1
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.initialInternalClientPassword=password2
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.authorizerName=MyBasicAuthorizer

## Creating an Escalator
# Escalator
druid.escalator.type=basic
druid.escalator.internalClientUsername=druid_system
druid.escalator.internalClientPassword=password2
druid.escalator.authorizerName=MyBasicAuthorizer


druid.auth.authorizers=["MyBasicAuthorizer"]
druid.auth.authorizer.MyBasicAuthorizer.type=basic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to include "druid-basic-security" as an extension

Visit https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/druid-basic-security.html

I need add "druid-basic-security" to common.runtime.properties like below

```
druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-hdfs-storage", "druid-kafka-indexing-service", "druid-datasketches", "druid-basic-security"]
```